# CKEditor bower global default config.js

Tags: angularjs, ckeditor, bower

I have an angular project where we use [angular-ckeditor](https://github.com/lemonde/angular-ckeditor). For this angular module I need ckeditor.js, which I installed through bower. Now we have multiple pages where we have ckeditor instances, but they all should use the same configuration.

With CKEditor you can change the default configuration [by changing the config.js](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_configuration). This however is not a good option, because when the application is deployed/shared/reinstalled bower installs the ckeditor scripts and so the config.js is also overwritten.

I know I can do something like `CKEDITOR.replace('myEditor', { customConfig: '/custom/path/to/config/ckeditor_config.js' });`, but this would be **per instance**, plus I don't know at runtime what the id's are for the editors.

Is there any other way to define **global** configuration for CKEditor? Without touching the config.js in its library?

**My possible ugly solutions:**

1. Check in the CKEditor scripts in source control, and don't install through bower (so the config.js won't be overridden)
2. Create a custom directive that just replaces the directive with the ckeditor and the customConfig configuration
3. Create a gulp task that overrides the config.js after the bower installation
4. Add id's to all ckeditors and use the `CKEditor.replace()` method
5. Pass the configuration to each instance of the ckeditor (`<textarea ckeditor="{ customConfig: 'myCustomConfig' }"></textarea>`)
6. Use a method that I missed in the documentation but does exist (**preferred! :)**)

What would be the 'best' solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I add ckeditor.config.js into index.html (my project using Grunt)
and link to ckeditor_config.js

```js
// scripts/libs/ckeditor.config.js
CKEDITOR.config.customConfig = "/scripts/libs/ckeditor_config.js";

// scripts/libs/ckeditor_config.js
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function (config) {
  config.toolbarGroups = [
    { name: 'mode' },
    { name: 'clipboard',   groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ] },
    { name: 'editing',     groups: [ 'find' ] },
    { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles' ] },
    { name: 'links' },
    { name: 'styles' },
    { name: 'cleanup' }
  ];
 config.removeButtons = 'Anchor,Strike,Styles,Font';
  //config.removePlugins = 'font';
  config.extraPlugins = "find,font";
}
```

```html
<!-- index.html -->
<script src="bower_components/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/libs/ckeditor.config.js"></script>
```

Comment: this is not a perfect solution as I prefer to create 1 extra file only ckeditor.config.js . however I cannot set config value inside that file directly.